# The most efficient algorithm to distribute items?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis

I am trying to design an algorithm that would help me distribute in this example case, 'students' to different exam rooms.

All the constraints for this Theoretical problem would be:

[1]"One student can only be at the exam room at a specific time "... meaning that only one student can give an exam in one of the rooms. No two students can share a room even if their exam starting times is exactly same.

[2]The number of rooms used has to remain a minimum.

[3] We could imagine that there are unlimited number of rooms that are available for use.

As inputs I only have the (sorted) exam starting times for students.

Can anyone suggest an algorithm which would always keep the number of "rooms used" to a minimum?

[Note: Multiple students may have the same exact starting times.]

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of a recently posted question?

Comment: `distribute […] 'students' to different exam rooms` & `algorithm [to minimise]  the number of "rooms used"` Assign all students to room 42 & 51. This [question about "distributing" students](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/80176/19966) may be similar.

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you tried proving it NP-complete?  Does it remind you of any NP-complete problem you're already familiar with?  (Hint: This is a special case of a NP-complete graph problem that you might  already be familiar with.)  It sounds like this is a theoretical problem, rather than a practical problem.  Can you share the source where you encountered the problem?  Is it in a course / textbook, and what topic are you studying now?  This is a nice exercise, so I will refrain from posting an answer for a little while, to give you a chance to solve it yourself.