# Determine whether a flow can satisfy node demands in a directed acyclic graph

Tags: graphs, network-flow

I have the following problem that I'm unsuccessfully trying to solve:

I have a directed graph with node demands. Unlike circulation with demands, these node demands do not "subtract" from the flow - the nodes merely demand that there would be a flow of strength *k* flowing through them. The graph is acyclic, however, it is not a tree - multiple routes exist from the higher to the lower nodes.

The question is, whether a flow of strength *R* can satisfy all of the nodes' demands. Of course, a flow with strength more than *k* can flow through a node with demand *k*. Also, there are no capacity limits in the input graph.

I need to reduce this problem to the max-flow problem. I have been trying to reduce it to Circulation with lower bounds and Circulation with demands, but unsuccessfully, as I am unable to find out a good way on how to somehow limit the flow in the nodes to be minimal while satisfying the demands and measuring it at the same time.

Comment: Can you clarify your problem? Where is the flow coming from? Is there a source vertex $s$? Where does it go to? Is there a target vertex $t$? If this is the case and the edge capacities are unbounded, isn't the problem equivalent to that of deciding whether all nodes with a positive demand lie on a simple path from $s$ to $t$? This would be easy to solve

Comment: There are *s* and *t* vertices, where source *s* is connected to every vertex that does not have any other incoming edges and sink *t* is connected to every vertex that does not have any outwards edges.

Comment: Also there does not have to be one single path on which all vertices lie - you might have to divide a flow of strength *R* into multiple paths so that every vertex is satisfied.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/116858/755

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a new source $s'$ and the edge $(s', s)$ with maximum and minimum capacity $R$.

For each vertex $v$ with demand $d$ do the following:

- Replace $v$ with two vertices $v_1$ and $v_2$.
- Replace all the former edges $(u,v)$ with $(u, v_1)$
- Replace all the former edges $(v, u)$ with $(v_2, u)$.
- Add the edge $(v_1, v_2)$ with minimum capacity $d$.

The problem is now equivalent to checking whether there exists a feasible flow in a network with minimum and maximum edge capacities.

This problem is well known and can be reduced to max-flow (see, e.g., "Balances and Pseudoflows" in the book [Algorithms](https://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/algorithms/) by Jeff Erickson).

Essentially, if $D$ is the sum of all the edges' minimum capacities:

- Add a new source vertex $s^*$ and a new target vertex $t^*$.
- Add the edge $(s^*, s')$ with maximum capacity $+\infty$.
- For each edge $(u,v)$ with minimum capacity $c \neq 0$ and maximum capacity $C$, add the edge $(u, t^*)$ with capacity $c$, the edge $(s^*, v)$ with capacity $c$, remove the minimum capacity from $(u,v)$, and change the maximum capacity of $(u,v)$ to $C-c$ (if $C$ was $+\infty$ then the new capacity is also $+\infty$).
- Check whether the maximum flow from $s^*$ to $t^*$ is equal to $D$.

Comment: Thanks, however it's not fully clear which capacities should have the 'original' edges $(u,v)$ in the modified at the first step network $(u, v_1)$, $(v_2,u)$ - $[0, +\infty]$ ? If I've got it right, the 'additional' edges $(v_1, v_2)$, $(u_1, u_2)$ etc., will receive instead of the $[d, +\infty]$ the new capacities $[0, +\infty]$ ("remove the minimum capacity from $(u, v)$")?

Comment: I think you got it right. All the edges in the original network have capacities $[0, +\infty]$. After the first phase, some of the edges had their endpoints changed (buy they keep their $[0, +\infty]$ capacity) while, for each vertex $v$ with minimum capacity $d$, the edge $(v_1,v_2)$ with capacity $[d,+\infty]$ is added.
After the second phase, an edge $(u,v)$ with capacity $[c,C]$ is transformed into 3 edges: $(s^*,v)$ with capacity $[0,c]$, $(u,t^*)$ with capacity $[0,c]$, and $(u,v)$ with capacity $[0,C-c]$, if $C=+\infty$ this is $[0,C-c]=[0,+\infty]$. All minimum capacities are now $0$.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation! It's become _almost_ clear - but just for the 'verification': the edge $(s^′, s)$ with the ($[R, R]$) capacity after the second phase will be split to the edges: 1. $(s^*, s^′)$ ($[0, R]$ capacity) // OK 2. $(s^′, s)$ ($[0, |R-R|=0]$ capacity) // confusing one 3. $(s, t^*)$ ($[0, R]$ capacity) // OK

Comment: You mixed up $s$ and $s'$ in some edges. $(s', s)$ will be split into $(s^*, s)$ with capacity $[0,R]$, $(s', t^*)$ with capacity $[0, R]$,  and $(s', s)$ with capacity $[0, 0]$ (you can even avoid adding this edge since it has capacity 0).  It is not related to the transformation of $(s', s)$ but, a part of the other steps of the construction, you will also add the edge $(s^*, s')$ of capacity $[0, +\infty]$.